# Spring Cloud Gateway route to itself

Tags: spring, routes, cloud, gateway

I have a scenario in an implementation of spring cloud gateway (Just for illustration call that service custom api gateway). In this 'Custom API Gateway' I want to define a route, filters, predicate and forward the request to a custom endpoint in the 'custom api gateway'? Is there a way to achieve that? Everything works except forwarding to a URI in the 'custom api gateway'

Here is an example

```
id: UpdateUser
uri:  SHOULD NOT GO DOWNSTREAM (endpoint is in 'custom api gateway')
predicates:
 - path=/api/users
filters:
 - ValidateSession
```

Thanks Segi

Comment: Hi Mohit Did you found the solution of it?

Answer (score 2):

You can define some controllers in spring cloud gateway and write routes to route requests to these controllers, but you should add uri changing filters like `prefixPath`, `stripPrefix` to change uri part to different one.

If you don't change the uri, requests will cause a [413 request entity too large](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/413) error code, if you open debug level log, you'll see gateway is passing this request over and over again to itself.