# [Spring Cloud Gateway]: RewritePath GatewayFilter not working for local forward route

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-webflux, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

**Spring cloud Gateway version: 4.1.0**

I have configured a route as follows which has downstream endpoint to a local REST API implemented in the gateway application itself as RestController:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: LocalRoute
          predicates:
            - Path=/local/**
          uri: forward:/local
          filters:
            - RewritePath=/local/(?<segment>.*), /token/$\{segment}
```

REST API is implemented as follows:

```
@GetMapping(value="/local/token", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public Mono<ResponseEntity<String>> createToken() {
   // Code to generate token and return in JSON format
}
```

When request is sent with url http://example.com:8080/local/token from Postman client, then request is intercepted correctly by the Gateway application.

```
RoutePredicateHandlerMapping | Route matched: LocalRoute
RoutePredicateHandlerMapping | Mapping [Exchange: GET http://example.com:8080/local/token] to Route{id='LocalRoute', uri=forward:/local, order=0, predicate=Path: [/local/**], match trailing slash: true, gatewayFitlers=[[[RewritePath /local/(?<segment>.*) = '/local/${segment}'], order = 1]], metadata={}}
```

Note: The request is first intercepted by Gateway application instead of directly by REST endpoint (by Spring DispatcherHandler) due to overridden configuration as described in below post:

[Spring Cloud Gateway as a gateway as well as web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70618318/spring-cloud-gateway-as-a-gateway-as-well-as-web-application)

```
@Component
public class RequestMappingHandlerMappingBeanPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {
    @Override
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        if (bean instanceof RequestMappingHandlerMapping) {
            ((RequestMappingHandlerMapping) bean).setOrder(2); // After RoutePredicateHandlerMapping
        }
        return bean;
    }
}
```

However when request is forwarded to local REST endpoint then the path segment is not getting appended in uri. That is the request is forwarded as **/local** instead of **/local/token** due to which request gets into recursion and throw StackOverflow exception.
Rest endpoint is not reached due to mismatch in request uri.

**Note**: When the endpoint is changed to http://localhost:8080/local (not with forward: prefix) for testing, then RewritePath filter appends path segment and result correctly to http://localhost:8080/local/token

I have referred following documents to fix the problem but none of them is workin:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/reference/spring-cloud-gateway/gatewayfilter-factories/rewritepath-factory.html

[Spring Cloud Gateway - Proxy/Forward the entire sub part of URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48865174/spring-cloud-gateway-proxy-forward-the-entire-sub-part-of-url)

How to append path segment in local forward route in Spring Cloud Gateway?